# How is the role of prices is different in market economy than to the command economy?

Tags: microeconomics

In command economy, like market economy, weren't the prices signal the government to alter their production according to shortages and surpluses? I am not able to differentiate the role of prices in both economic system.

Comment: A command economy is typically defined by the *absence* of a market mechanism and a "price signal". Prices are used in the distributional bookkeeping, but typically those prices are set centrally and apply to all transactions.